# Android VideoView: How to receive volume up/down indications in the app

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am playing a video in my app using VideoView. When I press Volume up/down buttons on the phone, the Media Volume is changed. Instead of that I want to receive notifications (methods OR intents etc.) so that my app can do customized action when Volume up/down is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, to hack volume key

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 
       //Do your thing  what you want...

     return true;
   } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to work as looks like VideoView is itself handling the keys and controlling Media Volume.

Comment: In my video application, I used this button for track changes.